# not able to create Kafka topic with Kafka Rest Proxy - HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException

Tags: post, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I am following this [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/rest-proxy.html#client). I am able to get cluster's information like this:

```
curl -sk -X GET "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/v3/clusters/"
```

the previous request works fine. However, when I try to create a topic I get **HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException** error

command:

```
curl -sk -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"topic_name\":\"test1\",\"partitions_count\":6,\"replication_factor\":3,\"configs\":[]}" \
     "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/v3/clusters/xxxxxxx/topics"
```

does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. any help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, this worked for me.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"
--data '{"records":[{"value":{"foo":"bar"}}]}' "https://localhost:8443/topics/test"
```

Answer (score 1):

The example from [this](https://rmoff.net/2020/06/05/how-to-list-and-create-kafka-topics-using-the-rest-proxy-api/) blog post worked for me:

```
POST http://localhost:8443/v3/clusters/<CLUSTER_ID>/topics
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "topic_name": "topic",
      "partitions_count": 1,
      "replication_factor": 2,
      "configs": []
    }
  }
}
```

So changing the Content-Type to `application/vnd.api+json` and using a different request body